# How to parallelise arrays inside a structure in OpenMP

Tags: openmp

I have a structure(pointer) G, which has multiple arrays, say A,B,C, etc.
I have parallelizable loops for these arrays. How do I implement OpenMP for these loops?

e.g. Code:

```
for(int i=;i<size,i++)
    G->A[i]=G->B[i]+G->C[i];
```

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for`

Comment: I know about this directive. But the issue is with the structure.